# Is there a phrase for "a close distance"?

Tags: phrases

I'm trying to describe a sense of distance that makes one feel his/her personal space is invaded. The context would be "She turned around, only to see him grinning at her from _____." I tried "a skip", but it somehow feels strange given the context. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Close up? Nearby?

Comment: She turned around only to find him right in her face, grinning [malevolently?]

Comment: A few inches/feet/yards away?

Comment: "No" means "no".

Comment: @MrKakuya: I think you're making a rod for your own back by supposing *le mot juste* should be something that can follow the word ***from*** (which in and of itself tends to imply *away, not here*). You might do better to forget about *from*, and consider alternative phrasing such as *"She turned around, only to see him **inches away**, grinning at her"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually I've shortened the sentense for a clearer structure, and the original context would be "She turned around at the unpleasant thud of human flesh hitting concrete walls, only to see the devil himself grinning at her from ___". I try to reduce the pauses here, because the sentense already seemed long enough, and the continuity of phrases would creat a sense of tension (I suppose?

Comment: @MrKakuya: The shortened version is quite enough to show the context in which you want to use *[le mot juste]*, so that's not a problem. I'm just saying that the fact of English having a *very* common collocation ***from afar*** doesn't imply you should expect to find a word with the "opposite" meaning to ***afar*** that can be slotted in with the same preposition ***from*** (partly because the preposition itself almost implies "distance, separation").

Comment: @FumbleFingers It makes a lot of sense when you put it in this way... thanks for the detailed explanation! What about "right in her face", like Jim suggested above?

Comment: @MrKakuya: Absolutely! **Right** commonly collocates with other words to form expressions having senses in the general area of "near, immediate", as ***right now, right away, right off, right here***.

Comment: In the original context, I think you should definitely keep the "from": "....only to see him inches away/right in her face, grinning FROM horn to horn!"

Comment: My first thoughts are that the best way to convey what you want will involve a more substantial rephrasing, not just a term to fill in the blank. Ideas for doing so likely be better and more appropriately obtained at writers.SE: http://writers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Avoid posting questions that do not provide clear criteria for useful answers – criteria that guide both answering and voting. This applies to word requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.

Comment: See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> She turned around only to see him grinning at her, a bit too close for comfort.

*too close for comfort* -[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=too%20close%20for%20comfort&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=too%20close%20for%20comfort%20meaning&revid=-1)

1. dangerously or **uncomfortably near**.

Answer (score 3):

If he had been following her very closely, tracking her every move, one could say he had been "breathing down her neck". This is an idiom.

From The Free Dictionary:
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/breathing+down+neck

---

Idioms:
breathe down (someone's) neck
1. To threaten by proximity, especially by pursuing closely.
2. To watch or monitor closely, often annoyingly: The boss was breathing down my neck all morning.

Answer (score 2):

The OP's sentence needs to be slightly reworded, but I think this solution works

> She turned only to see him grinning **directly behind** her

[directly behind](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/directly) without intervening space; next in order:
*The truck was parked directly behind my car.*

Comment: Actually the original context would be "She turned around at the unpleasant thud of human flesh hitting concrete walls, only to see the devil himself grinning at her from ___". With "directly behind", it seems to me that the connection between "the devil" and "her" is somewhat weakened...

Comment: @MrKakuya: I think Mari-Lou has the right approach here. If anything, doing away with ***from*** strengthens the connection between "the devil" and "her", because having it there in the first place *weakens, stretches out* that connection.

Answer (score 2):

> She turned around, only to see him grinning at her from _____.

How about

> She turned around, only to see him in her face, grinning.

Answer (score 0):

Proximity - The state of being near somebody/thing in distance or time.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd go with "She turned around, only to see him grinning at her right from within reach" or "within arms reach" meaning "he" is close enough to touch, thus invading "her" personal space.

If you want to describe more accurately where "he" is standing relative to "her's" position, you could also say he was "grinning at her from the adjacent (something like a fence post, tile or table) object of the same type "she" is stranding near. This will all depend on context, but i suggest you do a google search for "synonym: near" (without quotes) to find some more examples. It's also worth checking out antonyms of far while you're at it.

Comment: Would "within reach" or "within arms reach" leave the impression that "she wants to to touch him, thus she is measuring the distance with her arms"? (I know it's a idiom, but somehow it still makes my think about the possibility

Comment: It doesn't imply she would even want to reach out. It is simply an approximate measure, no more than two or three feet.

Answer (score 0):

You could take some liberty here with some creative prose; from a "breath's distance".  I think this crowd could come up with a bunch.

Answer (score -1):

"anear" - a tad archaic sounding, but if you insist on "...from", appropriate. Then again, as suggested above, you could use alternative means by dropping the "from".

Comment: anear is something you'd only hear Gandalf say

Answer (score -1):

What about ... She turned around, only to see him grinning at her from a "hair's breadth away"?

Comment: Avoid posting answers that lack explanation, context, and supporting facts. A good expert answer includes this information to demonstrate that it is correct. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page.

Expert partial answers are welcome, but notions, trial balloons, offhand ideas, guesses, anecdotes, and general discussion are not answers.

If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, a better way is to request clarification in a comment on the question.